# MS Ink или WM_MOUSE

Tags: windows, mfc

Необходимо сделать небольшое приложение на MFC, позволяющее рисовать мышью по холсту. Как это проще реализовать: используя обработку событий мыши или используя интерфейс предоставляемый MS Ink?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Удобство и легкость программирования подобного приложения нарастают при движении: WinAPI -> MFC -> WPF. Если приложение крайне простое (например, создаваемое в учебных целях), вполне можно использовать и WinAPI. Пример подобного подхода можно посмотреть по [ссылке](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms645602(v=vs.85).aspx) из MSDN (на английском). Для более серьезного приложения лучше использовать WPF. Тот же MS Ink, в виде элемента InkCanvas, позволит реализовать отслеживание мыши и рисование по холсту одной строкой в разметке (в WinAPI или MFC/GDI+ это потребует несколько страниц кода).

```
<InkCanvas />
```